# I would like to make a carousel using Bootstrap with 1 horizontal picture and (next slide) 2 vertical pictures. But I can`t make them the same height

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="carousel-example-generic" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Indicators -->
  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel-example-generic" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>


  <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

    <div class="item active">
        <img src="big1.JPG" alt="...">
    </div>

    <div class="item">
        <div class="row">
             <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="vertical2.JPG" class="img-responsive"></div>
             <div class="col-xs-6"><img src="vertical2.JPG" class="img-responsive"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </div>
    </div>
```

Here is my code, my vertical and horizontal pictures have the same height(256 px), but vertical pictures appears a little bit longer. I tried to solve this problem by: adding 256px height to container element and height: 100%; to my vertical pictures, but it did not work. I will very appreciate your advice. Thank you.

Comment: The problem is the width of your images. Make sure your vertical image has 50% of the width of the big image (if big image has 1000px width, your vertical image should have 500px) and make sure there is no margin between two vertical images.

Comment: @makshh Can I make different width, but the same height? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You have to make sure your vertical images have the same height and 50% width of the big image.
2. You have to remove gaps between vertical images.

CSS:

```
.item .row {
  margin: 0;
}
.item [class*="col"] {
  padding: 0;
}
```

### [CODEPEN](http://codepen.io/makshh/pen/wgzVVq)

If you have images with different width you have to set fixed height to all your images inside carousel.

```
.carousel .item img {
  height: 200px;
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to make different width, but the same height? Thank you for your example!

Comment: Read to the end ;)